# How to trigger TextInput when pressed anywhere on the TextInput box in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, input

So I am using TextInput component and its height is lets say "70%", and when I press in the middle of the TextInput it does not open. But when I press on top it opens. Do you have solution for this?

If you need any more info please comment.

Thanks!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Can you add the code , what you've added so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made sure that TextInput is has full width and height of parent component.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the height from"70%"to a number like 60,and also for width

Comment: that would mess up my responsive design

Comment: OK,so  if you wanna the height of your textInput to be 70% of your screen height,use height:0.7*height,would it mess up too?